# My wordpress site redirecting to differernt website

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming

My wordpress site redirecting to differernt website.

this is resonse from a redirect checker tools

```
Result
https://boshoneboshonto.com/
302 Found
https://yooshahpuwai.lol/?u=k8pp605&o=c9ewtnr&t=ggdown
200 OK

Problems found:
You use a 302 redirect. This means, that the actually content is temporary not reachable and will come back soon. To use a 302 redirection for generally moved pages is a bad idea. Search engine bot might not follow it or handle it as temporary. For SEO this is also a bad idea, because no link juice will be transferred to the linked page

>>> https://boshoneboshonto.com/

> --------------------------------------------
> 302 Found
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 302 Found
Code:   302
Connection: close
Location:   https://yooshahpuwai.lol/?u=k8pp605&o=c9ewtnr&t=ggdown
content-type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
cache-control:  no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
expires:    Sat, 24 Feb 2024 11:57:22 GMT
content-length: 0
date:   Sat, 24 Feb 2024 11:57:22 GMT
server: LiteSpeed
vary:   Accept-Encoding
alt-svc:    h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46"




>>> https://yooshahpuwai.lol/?u=k8pp605&o=c9ewtnr&t=ggdown

> --------------------------------------------
> 200 OK
> --------------------------------------------

Status: 200 OK
Code:   200
Server: nginx
Date:   Sat, 24 Feb 2024 11:57:23 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html
Content-Length: 61514
Connection: close
cache-control:  private
set-cookie: s1=m3e1b7oghosbztvr; path=/
Cache-Control:  no-transform
```

here is main website link: https://boshoneboshonto.com/

I tried many thing .

I changed function.php
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');

Comment: If you have a working site that suddenly starts redirecting to another site, my first assumption is that you have been hacked in some fashion. If that’s the case, fixing it will include hunting through both files and the database. You might want to look at restoring from a backup instead.

Comment: I recently took the project for update the site . My client told me they had this issue from the beginning .

Comment: “from the beginning” - by that, do you mean they’ve never had a home page? Or do they mean “a really long time”?

Comment: Please also share the content of the .htaccess file.